# One who wants to save his money but can't, is called what?

Tags: single-word-requests

For instance, if a person wants to save $200 but when he reaches at the saving of $50, spend it again and repent for that and could not save $200, which he wanted.

The term 'extravagant' is circulating in my mind but this is not the term that I want because this is an adjective.

I need noun for the one who wants his money be saved but is unable to do so.

Comment: What connotation are you looking for? Negative? Apologetic?

Comment: Positive Connotation. @ManOisdealbha

Comment: @ManOisdealbha Please, read the body of my question, again.

Comment: Does he spend the $50 because he has obligations and just doesn’t have enough income to maintain his savings or does he spend it because he’s undisciplined and easily succumbs to desires for instant gratification?

Comment: @Jim He spends $50 because
he’s undisciplined
and easily succumbs
to desires for instant
gratification.

Comment: Ok, but you want a positive connotation?  So something meaning he's carefree and denies himself nothing or that he lives in the moment?

Comment: @Jim He isn't carefree.

Comment: I’m having trouble seeing how this person who isn’t mature enough to manage a budget can be viewed in a positive light unless you view his devil-may-care attitude as an enviable quality.

Comment: @Jim Sir, please, first of all make me understand fully what's connotation and its types?

Comment: If a person wants to save money but cannot because they spend it on non-essential items, there is no way you can turn that into a positive trait.

Comment: If the reason for spending that money is to pay for bills and normal household expenditures (e.g. food for the family, car repairs, medical visits, etc.) then that is a totally different scenario. Please clarify which situation you are describing.

Comment: Related: [“Prodigal” vs. “spendthrift”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131742/prodigal-vs-spendthrift) and [Word for the habit of spending money on things that are not really needed](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62952/word-for-the-habit-of-spending-money-on-things-that-are-not-really-needed)

Comment: It seems to me that your question has been answered here: [What is the metaphoric antonym to “paycheck to paycheck living?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50393/what-is-the-metaphoric-antonym-to-paycheck-to-paycheck-living)

Answer (score 5):

**Spendthrift?**
 I'm not sure that a spendthrift is trying to save money, but they probably wish they had!

> [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spendthrift)
>   A spendthrift (also profligate or prodigal) is someone who spends money prodigiously and who is extravagant and recklessly wasteful, often to a point where the spending climbs well beyond his or her means. "Spendthrift" derives from an obsolete sense of the word "thrift" to mean prosperity rather than frugality,[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spendthrift) so a "spendthrift" is one who has spent their prosperity

Answer (score 0):

**impulsive**

> acting or done suddenly without any planning or consideration of the results:
>
> She’s an impulsive shopper and often buys things she doesn’t need.

[Cambridge](https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/impulsive)

Often an impulse purchase will wipe out savings, or just mean that you can't get to your target.

Comment: OP needs a noun...